# Except for the GPU, what can cause persistent graphical artifacts during boot?

Tags: boot, troubleshooting

I'm getting these graphical artifacts during boot, as early as the BIOS screen and during the Windows startup as well:

[image]

The pattern seems to stay identical, and it is visible on every single boot. I don't see any graphical artifacts once Windows has booted, though. I wouldn't worry too much about this, except that the computer is also rather unstable now and crashes occasionally. It is also not uncommon for the computer to simply stop during boot.

I'm guessing that these issues are caused by one component, and I want to narrow down what exactly might be broken so that I can exchange that part.

To preempt the obvious suggestion, I already replaced the GPU (ATI Radeon 4850) with a different one (NVidia 8800 GT) I had running without problems in a second computer.

I also ran Memtest86+, which ran through without a problem.

The details of the computer:

- Mainboard: Gigabyte EP35-DS3
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400
- NVidia 8800 GT
- Windows 7 32bit

What else could cause this specific issue? Any further test I could run to narrow it down?

Comment: Does your motherboard have onboard video? What GPU model were you using and what did you switch to? Did you try the GPU in a different slot?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't have onboard graphics, I added the information about the GPUs in my post.

Comment: This is a perfect description of the early stages of bump underfill cracking, even down to it going away as soon as the system warms up (the bumps expand and fill the cracks). Except you replaced the only GPU in your system.